# NginX cannot be run after renewing let's encrypt

Tags: nginx, restart

I did the following to do renewing my let's encrypt.

```
sudo systemctl stop ufw
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop
cd /opt/letsencrypt
./letsencrypt-auto renew 
sudo systemctl start ufw
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
```

When I was in "sudo systemctl start ufw"  line, it took a while and when I wanted to run "sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start" line my conenction lost. After reconnecting any attempts to run nginX failed as the below shows. I also restarted my droplet but still NginX failed to run.
I also should mentioned that I have renewed a couple of times so far with my current firewall, nginx setting. This is the first time that with the same setting I got this problem.

Thanks for the advices!

sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
[....] Starting nginx (via systemctl): nginx.serviceJob for nginx.service failed                    because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

```
systemctl status nginx.service
nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-10-31 20:35:29 UTC; 12s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 2741 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process
```

The error.log located at :/var/log/nginx are :

```
2020/10/31 22:13:45 [alert] 4175#4175: *2660 open socket #7 left in connection 20
2020/10/31 22:13:45 [alert] 4175#4175: *14143 open socket #3 left in connection 25
2020/10/31 22:13:45 [alert] 4175#4175: *5994 open socket #4 left in connection 31
2020/10/31 22:13:45 [alert] 4175#4175: *26302 open socket #19 left in connection 37
2020/10/31 22:13:45 [alert] 4175#4175: aborting
2020/10/31 22:15:18 [emerg] 23562#23562: duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save:31
2020/10/31 22:15:22 [emerg] 23611#23611: duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save:31
2020/10/31 22:16:14 [emerg] 23751#23751: duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save:31
2020/10/31 22:16:35 [emerg] 23803#23803: duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save:31
2020/10/31 22:16:50 [emerg] 24025#24025: duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save:31
2020/10/31 22:17:33 [emerg] 24486#24486: duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save:31
2020/10/31 22:18:55 [emerg] 24551#24551: duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save:31
2020/10/31 22:19:07 [emerg] 24601#24601: duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save:31
2020/10/31 22:22:32 [emerg] 25234#25234: duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save:31
2020/10/31 22:23:46 [emerg] 25290#25290: duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save:31
2020/10/31 22:23:55 [emerg] 25340#25340: duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save:31
2020/10/31 22:27:40 [emerg] 878#878: duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save:31
2020/10/31 22:30:38 [emerg] 1942#1942: duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save:31
2020/10/31 22:30:54 [emerg] 2178#2178: duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save:31
2020/10/31 22:31:13 [emerg] 2258#2258: duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save:31
2020/10/31 22:35:29 [emerg] 2741#2741: duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save:31
2020/10/31 22:36:43 [emerg] 2793#2793: duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save:31
2020/10/31 22:42:30 [emerg] 2860#2860: duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save:31
2020/10/31 22:48:20 [emerg] 3100#3100: duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save:31
2020/10/31 22:52:42 [emerg] 3975#3975: duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save:31
2020/10/31 22:53:15 [emerg] 4026#4026: duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save:31
```

Comment: What is in nginx error log?

Comment: When ever I add "sudo systemctl start ufw" the connection lost.  @IvanShatsky where can I access to log? thanks

Comment: Check your nginx config, the full path is specified via `error_log` directive.

Comment: @IvanShatsky I added thanks

Comment: Looks like something wrong with the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save` file. Moreover, looks like this file shouldn't be there at all. Can you just move it somewhere and try to start nginx?

Comment: @IvanShatsky yes there is a default.save and default1.save that are there since 202-08-13 ( perhaps the last time before this time that I renewed let's encrypt). I changed the permission to delete it ( I got a back up) but it gives me  Permission denied.
Error code: 3
Error message from server: Permission denied.  It looks a process is using that right? I use my admin permission but still I could not delete it . 
rm: remove write-protected regular file '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save'? y
rm: cannot remove '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save': Permission denied

Comment: You can check that with `lsof`.

Comment: @IvanShatsky : No I do not see that in the list certainly. Are you sure should I delete this file?

Comment: I found the problem. Actually it looks /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save should not be deleted but the problem was related to new nginx that it looks it is updated via my service provider to edit the file and remove ip6only part. I got the solution from here https://serverfault.com/questions/842492/nginx-duplicate-listen-options-for-80-error